# How to configure the AVR board for ADC?

Tags: assembly, avr, adc

I have a sample code for analog to digital converter but I cannot see the expected results on my Mikroelektronika ATMEGA32 developer board. The only reason I come up with is the locations of jumpers. I've plugged two of them PB2 and PB3 which are located near the potentiometers. Does anyone have suggestions?

```html
/*
 * Lab4_ADC.asm
 *
 *  
 */ 

;***** Constants
.equ preset=192   ;T/C0 Preset constant (256-64) 
;***** A/D converter Global Registers
.def result=r16   ;Result and intermediate data
.def temp=r17   ;Scratch register
.def temp2=r20
.def temp3=r21

;***********************************************************
;*   PROGRAM START - EXECUTION STARTS HERE
;***********************************************************
.cseg
.org $0000
jmp RESET      ;Reset handle
.org OVF0addr
jmp ANA_COMP   ;Timer0 overflow handle
.org ACIaddr
jmp ANA_COMP   ;Analog comparator handle

RESET:
 ldi  TEMP, low(RAMEND) ; initialize stack pointer
 out SPL, TEMP
 ldi  TEMP, high(RAMEND)
 out  SPH, TEMP
 rcall convert_init  ;Initialize A/D converter
 ldi result,$ff  ;set port D as output
 out DDRD,result  ;for LED’s
 sei    ;Enable global interrupt
Delay: 
 clr temp2   ;Clear temp counter 1
 ldi temp3,$f0  ;Reset temp counter 2
loop1: 
 inc temp2   ;Count up temp counter 1
 brne loop1   ;Check if inner loop is finished
 inc  temp3   ;Count up temp counter 2
 brne  loop1   ;Check if delay is finished
 
 rcall AD_convert  ;Start conversion
Wait:
 brtc Wait   ;Wait until conversion is complete (T flag set)
 out PORTD,result  ;Write result on port C
 rjmp Delay   ;Repeat conversion

convert_init:
 ldi     result,(1<<ACIE)|(1<<ACIS1)|(1<<ACIS0)  ;Initiate comparator
 out     ACSR,result     ; enable comparator interrupt
 ldi     result,(1<<TOIE0)         ;Enable timer interrupt
 out     TIMSK,result
 sbi     DDRB,PB1          ;Set converter charge/discharge pin
 cbi     DDRB,PB3   ;AIN1 ;Voltage input to the comparator
 ret     ;Return from subroutine

AD_convert:
 ldi result,preset     ;Load offset value (192)
 out TCNT0,result      ;to the counter
 clt     ;Clear conversion complete flag (t)
 cbi DDRB, PB2   ;AIN0 ;Disconnect discharging, input to comp.
 ldi result,(1<<CS01)  ;Start timer0 with prescaling f/8
 out TCCR0,result

 sbi PORTB,PB1    ;Start charging of capacitor
 ret      ;Return from subroutine

;Interrupt handler for A/D Comparator and overflow
ANA_COMP:        
 in result,TCNT0     ; Get timer value
 clr temp       ; Stop timer0
 out TCCR0,temp         
 subi result,preset+1  ; Rescale A/D output 
        ;(+1 for int. delay)

 cbi PORTB,PB1        ;Start discharge
 sbi DDRB, PB2  ;AIN0 ;Make discharging pin an output
     ;it automatically becomes low
 set    ;Set conversion complete flag (T flag)
 reti               ;Return from interrupt
```